# git subtree/submodule equivalent in tfs?

Tags: git, tfs

Does anyone know whether TFS has similar function likes git subtree or submodule?

That is one repository contains sub-repositories.

---

I rewrite my question in other words:

1. We knew git has ability to combine/reference other repo in current repo via subtree/submodule function.
2. Does TFVC has same function likes git ?

---

**Answer:**
@starain-msft said, submodule isn't supported in TFVC

Comment: I am locked in a team which is using TFS. I have no experience on TFS but used git for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TFS supports Git version control too, you can push your local repository with subtree or submodule to a Git repository in TFS.

Some articles:

[Git and Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/overview)

[One TFS Build, Multiple Git Repositories with Submodules](https://www.benday.com/2016/11/04/one-tfs-build-multiple-git-repositories-with-submodules/)

Comment: The team is using TFVC.

Comment: @Raymond The TFVC team project supports git repository after TFS 2015 update 1. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/team-projects

Comment: @Raymond You can create multiple folders in the TFVC source control, similar to subtree, but submodule isn't supported in TFVC.

Comment: Oh, `submodule isn't supported in TFVC`

Answer (score 0):

The Only Solution I found useful for you is : [Git-TFS](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs)

> [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) is a two-way bridge between TFS (Team Foundation Server)
>   and git, similar to git-svn. It fetches TFS commits into a git
>   repository, and lets you push your updates back to TFS.

Comment: I am using this tool for months. Most similar thing is `git-tfs subtree`https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/subtree.md  but it is not the answer of my question.